# Updating the log-density of a multivariate probit latent class model

Tags: performance, rcpp

I am new to Rcpp and am looking to make the following code as fast as possible. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

It is running a lot slower than I would like.

I have tried vectorising as much as possible but i'm not sure how to vectorise further

In R I can vectorise this easily so i'm pretty sure it should be possible to vectorise it all in Rcpp too (do you get similar benefits from vectorisation in C++ as you do in R?)

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat  fn_update_log_posterior(arma::mat current_logdiffs_set_mat,
                                     int K,
                                     int N,
                                     int l_class,
                                     int ord_test,  
                                     int n_bin_tests, 
                                     arma::mat first_cutpoint_mat,
                                     arma::mat prev,
                                     arma::cube prob_test,
                                     arma::mat prob,
                                     arma::vec class_ind,
                                     arma::cube Xbeta,
                                     double prior_ind_dir,
                                     arma::mat yp1,
                                     arma::mat y,
                                     double prior_densities) { 
  
  arma::mat current_cutpoints_set_full = fn_calculate_cutpoints(current_logdiffs_set_mat, first_cutpoint_mat, K);
  arma::mat log_prob(1,1);
  arma::vec lp(N);
  arma::vec lower_ord_inv_prob(N); 
  arma::vec upper_ord_inv_prob(N);
  arma::vec lower_ord_prob(N); 
  arma::vec upper_ord_prob(N);
  arma::mat prob_test_n(prob_test.n_cols, prob_test.n_slices);

    for (int n = 0; n < N;++ n) {

          upper_ord_inv_prob.at(n) = current_cutpoints_set_full.at(yp1.at(n, ord_test))    - Xbeta.at(l_class , n , ord_test);
          lower_ord_inv_prob.at(n) = current_cutpoints_set_full.at(y.at(n, ord_test))      - Xbeta.at(l_class, n , ord_test);
          
         
    }
    
    upper_ord_prob = fn_Phi_approx_vec_2(upper_ord_inv_prob);
    lower_ord_prob = fn_Phi_approx_vec_2(lower_ord_inv_prob);


   for (int n = 0; n < N; ++n) {
     
           prob_test.at(n, ord_test, l_class) =       log( upper_ord_prob(n)  - lower_ord_prob(n) );
     
           prob_test_n = prob_test.row(n);
    
           prob.at(n,l_class) = sum(prob_test_n.col(l_class)) + log(prev.at(0, l_class));
          
            lp.at(n) =  prob.at(n,class_ind(n) - 1); // works for any number of classes
   }
      
    
    
    log_prob(0,0) = sum(lp) + prior_densities;

    
    return(log_prob);
  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! To help reviewers give you better answers, we need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*.  Please add sufficient context to your question to describe the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  Also, [edit] the **title** to simply [**summarise the task**](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Comment: You need to explain what the code is doing. This should be also be present in the title.

Comment: @convert it's updating the log-density of a multivariate probit latent class model. I am wondering if the for loops can be vectorised for example. It's possible to vectorise this in R so I dont see why it shouldn't be in Rcpp

Comment: So I changed the title then.

Comment: Thank you @convert